# VBA: Copy/paste only numerical values

Tags: vba

I'm working on a macro that imports a lot of data, currently using .PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteValues

This is fine as long as all ranges contain numerical values only. However, on some sheets, instead of using zeroes there are dashes "-", which complicate calculations down the road. I guess Excel treat those as values.

My temporary solution is to use a loop to scan through the last imported range for dashes and replace them with zeroes. Since the amount of data is quite substantial I'd prefer a solution that automatically treats non-numerical values as zeroes to increase efficiency of the code.

It's important that the dashes are treated as zeroes rather than ignored, since positioning must be maintained.

The calculation in question is a variant array multiplication (containing the imported values) assigned to a double.

Comment: Run a find/ replace on the pasted data, replacing - with 0

Comment: This is manual labor, which is not VBA. Replace function will work. In addition, another function canbe created which will go character by character; if character is not the number, replace with 0.

Comment: @Andrew: You can run a find/replace using VBA...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to do this:

```
NewValue = Replace(OldValue,"-","0")
```

Comment: Might be worthwhile to add that this can be done on the whole range, as opposed to looping through each cell to perform this operation.

Comment: @Gaffi: How exactly? The `Replace` function doesn't accept a `Range` as an argument...

Comment: Instead of doing something like "For Each Cell In Range - Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, "-", 0) - Next Cell" You can just do "Range.Value = Replace(Range.Value, "-", 0)" - At least that what I tested in Excel 2003...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Gaffi's solution is the best one so far, so I'll stick with that!

Answer (score 1):

Just replace all `-` in one go:

```
Range("B2:B6").Replace What:="-", Replacement:="0"
```